# How do I solve this Selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got an WebDriverException error, saying that chromedriver.exe needs to be in path, but as you see in the second picture, I have already done that. I am also having trouble figuring out the "unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"). Attached is the error. Right now I am using this website (https://christophegaron.com/scraping-linkedin-posts-with-selenium-and-beautiful-soup/) to download Chrome Driver and Selenium to my laptop (I already have BeautifulSoup on my laptop so I don't need that one). Also, I have both Ubuntu and Linux, so I am open to using either to solve my issue. I am also using Python 3.8.5, Ubuntu 20.04.2, Chrome version 91, and Linux version 4.4.0.

Also if anyone has any tips regarding how to scrape LinkedIn posts that would be amazing!

[picture of the errors/exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLE7I.png)
[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q6KH.png)

Comment: If you run `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` from a command line, does it run?

Comment: And, by the way, Ubuntu is Linux.

Comment: I tried running /usr/local/bin/chromedriver, and it says "only local connections are allowed"

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Comment: After updating chromium and chromiumdriver and adding more add_arguments (such as --no-sandbox and --disable-dev-shm-usage) I solve my previous errors (unknown error - chrome failed to start) I have a new error ("message-unknown error - session deleted because of page crash. from tab crashed (session info: headless chrome=91)). It seems that when I add in more arguments, the errors seem to decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! I found that my error was that I was using Ubuntu on a Linux machine (as a VM), when I should have just ran the Chromium program on a natural machine.